# translate a native OS fileDialog with Qt application

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, translation, qfiledialog

I want to translate my QfileDialog using native OS component to a specific language which is different than the current OS locale Language.

the `QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog` option allows to translate the Qt widget, but it is an old design and I don't like to use it if another solution is possible.

I found the following:

```
   QFileDialog d;
   d.setLabelText( QFileDialog::Accept,tr("Open") );
   d.setLabelText( QFileDialog::Reject,tr("Cancel") );
   d.setLabelText( QFileDialog::FileName,tr("File name") );
   d.setLabelText( QFileDialog::LookIn,tr("Look in") );
```

but this has not translated the "cancel" button. it only worked for "Open" and "File name" labels.

can some one tell me how to fix it for the "cancel" button or what is wrong with it?

any other solution is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

you haven't done anything wrong. It is currently somewhat a bug in Qt (Bugtracker: [QTBUG-44112](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-44112)). The problem is, that Qt uses the IFileDialog interface to communicate with the native OS file dialog. That interface doesn't allow changing the reject button's label. Here's the Qt code handling renaming labels for this native dialog:

```
void QWindowsNativeFileDialogBase::setLabelText(QFileDialogOptions::DialogLabel l, const QString &text)
{
  wchar_t *wText = const_cast<wchar_t *>(reinterpret_cast<const wchar_t *>(text.utf16()));
  switch (l) {
  case QFileDialogOptions::FileName:
    m_fileDialog->SetFileNameLabel(wText);
    break;
  case QFileDialogOptions::Accept:
    m_fileDialog->SetOkButtonLabel(wText);
    break;
  case QFileDialogOptions::LookIn:
  case QFileDialogOptions::Reject:
  case QFileDialogOptions::FileType:
  case QFileDialogOptions::DialogLabelCount:
    break;
  }
}
```

As you can see, trying to set the reject button's label (or the other options) is simply being ignored. Not the best solution on Qt's part to be honest. They could have at least implemented a qWarning() or something to tell us that it is pointless what we're trying to do.

Anyhow, this bug is quite old, it has been assigned to a Qt developer, it hasn't been closed yet, but it has a low priority.

I know, not the answer you were hoping for.

Comment: yes i found that, and the bug is resolved in QT5.9 i think , i tried with QT5.10 and the cancel button text is updated. and i finished by adoption the `QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog` option , because in native OS dialog there will be more texts and options to translate